# error message: invalid allocation size

Tags: c++, allocation

I have two classes:

```
class A {
   long int m_Code;
   char m_Name[NAME_LEN];
   bool vec[2]; 
};

class B {
   A* movie;
   char time[LEN_TIME]; 
};

class C {
  int theater_number; 
  B *b;
};

class D {
   C* vec;
 public:
  void allocate() { vec = new C[10]; } // create a vector: 10 elements of A
};
```

but I got an error message of: invalid allocation size: 2425452 bytes

Comment: Well you left the important part out. What is the exact number that `*` represents?

Comment: What do you mean "when * is a number"? Can you give an example of that?

Comment: What you have posted works fine for me and looks ok, so there must be something important left out.

Comment: I tried your posted code. it compiles OK.

Comment: I write the real classes.. (and the real number)

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which OS?

Comment: Is the error occurring at compile time or at run time?  Also, what else are you `#include`'ing in this header or the implementation file?  I have a feeling the error is in some other code that is compiled at the same time as what you've posted; what you've posted works for me and several other people as well based on the other comments.

Comment: it was my mistake.. I defined: vec = new C[size]; but didn't define the size.. a stupid mistake :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>***Disclaimer: A lot of guesswork involved***</sup>

I believe that the reason is that you haven't properly defined

`NAME_LEN`

or

`LEN_TIME`

or have defined them to have a value that is too large.

Comment: I defined it by: #define LEN_TIME 6 and defined: #define NAME_LEN 100

Comment: @AlonShmiel: Yet you accepted my answer? How am I to interpret that?

Comment: [Close enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598944/error-message-invalid-allocation-size#comment22120341_15598944), I'd think.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah, I see... I knew there was something off with that 10 :)